# Complex Number equation: $z+2\bar{z}= |\bar{z}+3|$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve $z+2\bar{z}= |\bar{z}+3|$.

I'm new to complex numbers and need help solving this equation. Appreciate the assistance. Thanks.

**Edit: I've understood it now, i have to compare the real and imaginary parts. Thanks everyone, have a great day ahead!

Comment: The question is no longer open.

Comment: @Nick Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Since

$$z+2\bar z=|\bar z+3|$$

and $z+\bar z=2Re(z)$ we have that $z=\bar z=x$ is real then it reduces to solve

$$3x=|x+3|$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $z=x+iy$ then
$$(x+iy)+(2x-2iy)=|x-iy+3|$$
$$3x-iy=|(x+3)-iy|$$
shows
$$3x=|(x+3)-iy|~~~~~\text{and}~~~~~-iy=0$$
can you proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $z+2\overline z$ must be real, which is only possible if $z$ is real !

Then $$3x=|x+3|$$

and $x$ must be positive.

Finally,

$$3x=x+3.$$